# Bootstrap-vue form validation based on laravel backend: Error message shows but form input still is in valid state. Any ideas?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I am working on a project that requires me to do some backend validation for VAT numbers.

First I use client side Vue Bootstrap form validation to make sure all required fields are filled in. If this succeeds, I make a post request to the database.

When backend VAT validation fails, a json is returned with the error.

When my front end receives the error message, I want to change the VAT input that was previously labeled as succesfully validated, to failed.

To do this, I use the :state prop as mentioned in https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/form#validation .

When I do this, the errormessage shows up as expected but the border around the input is still green, as if it was a correct input.

Does anyone have an ideas of what may cause this and how to fix it?

Below you can see a link to images of both the errormessage showing below a green bordered form input (it should be red since it's an error), and a few snippets of relevant code.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7cdG.jpg

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the value of `VATValid` show as `false` when the error is received?

Comment: copy the code here instead of screenshots of it.